# Please don't snow when I'm not there

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2014

Yay! [Winterbash!](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com) Hats! Countdown! Wow!

Except I came back to the tab after 20 minutes:

[image: Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo]

It almost crashed my browser. Please can it not snow when the tab is not active?

Comment: I'd also like to register my disappointment that there is no hat for hacking the countdown.

Comment: The memory usage of that tab is stable for me in Chrome, it uses a hefty amount of CPU, but doesn't seem to leak memory here.

Comment: Chrome 39, Yosemite, snowgeddon.

Comment: Chromium 41 on Windows 7, accumulation. No memory leak though.

Comment: I just noticed, snow only accumulates if the tab isn't active, it doesn't accumulate if the tab is visible

Comment: In fact it's simple: snow accumulates if the tab is inactive, and fall when I reopen the tab.

Comment: And now, after leaving it for a couple of minutes, Task Manager shows the tab memory steadily increasing. I spoke too soon.

Comment: @mmyers Yup. It keeps adding the snowflakes to the page, but it's not rendering/removing them. When you do switch to it, it tries to render several thousand snowflakes and (in my case at least) locks up.

Comment: Sometimes snow causes disruption of essential services; do you have enough bread and milk in case you get stranded?

Comment: Blizzard after 30 minutes!!!

Comment: @Laura It's not bread and milk I don't have enough of, it's memory!

Comment: @A.L I said almost. It was struggling to render the thousands and thousands of snowflakes that it had been drawing all that time

Comment: howlonguntilwinterbash.com

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Fine fine fine. Can't handle a bit of snow, hmm?

Just find something to do with it!

[image: refridgerator made out of snow]

Comment: What kind of knock-off Fireball whiskey is that? -1.